# Guessing game with classes

Tags: python, class, module

So for some reason that eludes me, the `game_mechanics` method in this code doesn't seem to be operating and I am not sure why. The `new_game()` to `Number_Game()` seems to pass alright, so I am at a loss as to why the rest isn't working.

```
from random import randint

class Number_Game() :
  secret_num = randint(0,10)

  def __init__(self):
    self.user_numb_guesses = 0
    self.user_play = 0
    self.secret_num = randint(0,10)
    self.user_act_guess = 0

  def game_mechanics(self) :
    self.user_act_guess = int(input("Pick a number, any whole number, between 0 and 10. Choose wisely." ))
    if self.user_act_guess > 10:
      print ("You have chosen poorly, I said to choose a number between 1 and 10.")
      self.user_act_guess = int(input("Choose again"))
      self.user_numb_guesses = self.user_numb_guesses + 1

    if self.user_act_guess > self.secret_num :
      print ("You have chosen poorly, my number is smaller than that. You have guessed wrong %d times." % self.user_numb_guesses)
      self.user_act_guess = int(input("Try again, choose a number between 1 and 10"))
      self.user_numb_guesses = self.user_numb_guesses + 1

    if self.user_act_guess < self.secret_num :
      print ("You have chosen poorly, my number is larger than that. You have guessed wrong %d times." % self.user_numb_guesses)
      self.user_act_guess = int(input("Try again, choose a number between 1 and 10"))
      self.user_numb_guesses = self.user_numb_guesses + 1

    if self.user_act_guess == self.secret_num :
      self.user_play = int(input("Congratulations! You have chosen wisely, %d was the number I was thinking of.It only took you %d tries. Press 1 to keep playing." % (self.user_act_guess , self.user_numb_guesses)))
      if self.user_play == 1 :
            new_game()

def new_game():
  user_play = input("Enter 1 to play the guessing game")
  while user_play != "1" :
    new_game()
  if user_play == "1" :
    Number_Game()

new_game()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem.

Comment: **How** is it not "operating"?

Comment: It asks whether or not the user wants to play and then the program simply ends. It's not moving on to the game_mechanics() portion of the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

class Number_Game() :

  def __init__(self):
    self.user_numb_guesses = 0
    self.user_play = 0
    self.secret_num = randint(0,10)
    self.user_act_guess = 0
    self.game_mechanics() # This is new


  def game_mechanics(self) :
      while(True): # This is new
        self.user_act_guess = int(input("Pick a number, any whole   number, between 0 and 10. Choose wisely." ))
        if self.user_act_guess > 10:
          print ("You have chosen poorly, I said to choose a number between 1 and 10.")
          # self.user_act_guess = int(input("Choose again"))
          self.user_numb_guesses = self.user_numb_guesses + 1

        if self.user_act_guess > self.secret_num :
          print ("You have chosen poorly, my number is smaller than that. You have guessed wrong %d times." % self.user_numb_guesses)
          # self.user_act_guess = int(input("Try again, choose a number between 1 and 10"))
          self.user_numb_guesses = self.user_numb_guesses + 1

        if self.user_act_guess < self.secret_num :
          print ("You have chosen poorly, my number is larger than that. You have guessed wrong %d times." % self.user_numb_guesses)
          # self.user_act_guess = int(input("Try again, choose a number between 1 and 10"))
          self.user_numb_guesses = self.user_numb_guesses + 1

        if self.user_act_guess == self.secret_num :
          self.user_play = int(input("Congratulations! You have chosen wisely, %d was the number I was thinking of.It only took you %d tries. Press 1 to keep playing." % (self.user_act_guess , self.user_numb_guesses)))
          # if self.user_play == 1:
          #     new_game()
          break
      if self.user_play == 1:
          new_game()

def new_game():
  user_play = input("Enter 1 to play the guessing game")
  while user_play != "1" :
    new_game()
  if user_play == "1" :
    Number_Game()

new_game()
```

I have modified a few lines.

Comment: Omg thank you so much. I didn't realize I didn't need to have the self.user_act_guess = int(input) sequence. I thought I needed to ask that. I banged my head against the wall for a good long while. 

Thank you again so much.